# DQ9 - What effects does "Line-up" (Front Row / Back Row) have?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

What advantages/disadvantages are there to moving a character between the two formation rows in DQIX?

I believe the game said that characters in the back row will be attacked less, but I'm wondering if they also have their attack damage lowered or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The characters in the back row will be targeted less often by enemies.  There is no effect on the attack damage or critical rate of those characters in the back row.
(http://www.gamespot.com/ds/rpg/dragonquestix/answers.html?qid=2414560)

Comment: How much less often? Seems strange to me that there's no disadvantages to moving people back, so should I keep everyone except my best "tank" in the back row all the time?

Comment: A fair question!  Alas, I haven't been able to find anything other than anecdotal information on this.  Based on my playing, it seems that having 1 in front and 3 in back leads to a higher chance of someone in the back getting hit than does a 2 and 2 configuration.  So it seems like the effect is lessened somewhat by having more characters in the back.